# How to add Message driven bean (MDB) listen to topic on multiple remote machines? Is it possible to configure a remote at runtime?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, hornetq

I am new to JBoss and EJB. I am using JBoss AS7.1.1 for a message driven bean listen to a topic on remote machine. The setup we have is there is a primary and secondary MQ servers for which the MDB has to listen.

Can I specify a list of remote addresses in this HornetQ custom property?

```
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="connectorClassName", propertyValue="org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="connectionParameters", propertyValue="host=remotehost-a;port=5445"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "user", propertyValue = "jmsuser"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "password", propertyValue = "password")
```

Is it possible to configure MDB at runtime (may be thru deployment descriptor?) to have a new set of remote MQ server addresses (remotehost-b, remotehost-c, etc )?

Please provide some pointers on this. Thanks.